# Create an .EXE thats Calls a function from a .dll

Tags: c#, reflection, emit

so i have a .dll with a function(static or instance, i can change it, and still works) and i want to create an Exe with a Main as entry point, that reads the command line, and calls the funcion from the .dll

This is the method i am trying to call

```
 public static void Add(String a, String b)
 {
  Console.WriteLine( "{0} + {1}=  {2}", a, b , a+b);
 }
```

-so i load the dll assembly, and get the type that has the function that i want

```
        Assembly asmLoaded = Assembly.LoadFrom(nameDLL);
        Type baseType = asmLoaded.GetType(typeName);
```

-Create the new assembly, module and type for the new Exe

```
AssemblyName aName = new AssemblyName("AppAsm");

        AssemblyBuilder ab =
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
            aName,
            AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save);

        ModuleBuilder mb =
        ab.DefineDynamicModule("AppMod", typeName + methodName + ".exe");

        TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType("AppType", TypeAttributes.Public);
```

-Get the methodInfo from the method that i wan to call, and its parameter Types[] for the later Emit(Opcodes.Call,..);

-Then i define the Method, "Main", to be the entry point

```
 MethodBuilder metb = tb.DefineMethod("Main", MethodAttributes.Public |
            MethodAttributes.Static, null, new Type[] { typeof(String[])});
 ab.SetEntryPoint(metb);
```

-By using ildasm, i tried to do this part, Generating the IL

```
 ILGenerator il = metb.GetILGenerator();
 for (int i = 0; i <paramTypes.Length; ++i)
        {
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // get the String[], in 0 cause its static
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4,i);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelem_Ref);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, i);
        }         
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, 0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, 1);
        il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, wantedMethodInfo, paramTypes);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

-finally i create the Type, and save the assemblyBuilder

```
tb.CreateType();
ab.Save(typeName + methodName + ".exe");
```

And of course it doesnt work, xD
when i run the exe generated with some values, it throws
*System.InvalidProgramException: Common Languafe Runtime detected an invalid program. in AppTYpe.Main(String[] )*
i think i should probably Pop, some stuff out of the stack, but not sure.

Comment: Mmmm... *pop some stuff out of the stack* Why not add a reference to the DLL from your main code?

Comment: how would i do that ? is there an Emit(Opcodes.) to do that, or in c#?

Comment: Did you declare the locals?

Comment: no, i have to declare, to the il, from the metod in the dll?

Answer (score 1):

I would use expression trees to generate this (simple) `Main` function. You can use the `CompileToMethod` method to convert from expression tree to a `MethodBuilder`.

Also, the way to debug this is to run PEVerify.

Unable to tell you where specifically the IL is wrong because I can't see what method you want to call. You need to throw this away. Use expression trees.

What's also a strange choice is that you are using locals at all. You can do:

```
ldelem 0
ldelem 1
ldelem ...
call
ret
```

In pseudo code.

Comment: never heard of this, but ill look it up. This expressions trees, remove the need to have the il.Emits() ?

Comment: Yeah delete all of it. Or post the method signature and I'll probably spot the bug right away...

Comment: also, if the method i want to call is a Instance method, i need to create an instance of the class, and push it to the stack, after or before i push the arguments?

Comment: i was using that for, to get the values from the command line, cause if i change the signature of the function to get 3 values, i just have to run the code, not change anything

Comment: OK, so you are calling a (double, double) method with string arguments. That can't work! Expression trees are becoming even more attractive now because they give you sane error messages.

Comment: Same exception with, 2 strings as parameters

Comment: Then finally run PEVerify.

Comment: gives 1 Error, number of local variable not acknowledged. someone said to declare locals, not sure what that is

Comment: Oh yeah you need to declare the locals. I have not done IL generation for quite a while. You need to follow up more on what I say: You don't need locals at all. Simply remove them and the problem goes away. Alternatively you can Google for "ILgenerator declare locals".